# PyInstaller on cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, pyinstaller

I need to create an .exe file from a .py file on cygwin. Since py2exe doesn't seem to work there, I tried PyInstaller. However I have a problem installing it. `pip install pyinstaller` returns this message:

```
ERROR: Failed compiling the bootloader. Please compile manually and rerun setup.py
```

So I tried to follow this guide: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bootloader-building.html and install it manually. But when I run `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz` the folder that I get for PyInstaller is not https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller but this one: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tree/develop/PyInstaller in which there are no waf files and I can't run `python ./waf all`.
So I downloaded the needed folder from github manually and then `python ./waf all` succeded. However, I still can't not use PyInstaller since I get this error when trying to call it from command line:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyInstaller.__main__'
```

And I have no clue how to fix it. What should I do to get PyInstaller working or maybe I need to to use some other module that works with cygwin?

Comment: Can you use python from www.python.org instead of cygwin's python ?

Comment: @Philippe I don't really get what you mean. I am using SageMath Shell and it has pre-installed cygwin python with the modules I need. I am not sure that I can replace it with stadard python.

Comment: I don't know `SageMath Shell`. I guess if it works with cygwin python, it should work with standard python. I tested successfully pyinstaller with standard python, and had problems as well with cygwin python.